# Is it possible to generate a class diagram from my Visual Studio project environment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, uml, business-rules

Actually i have a Visual Studio 2019 project that which are going to updated trought of a new programing languaje, a new microservice architechture and a new data base manager.
i have the project like Visual Studio 2019 solution and i asked to me, if is possible with Visual Studio generate the class diagram of my project automatically??? because i only have this project such a documentation and reference frame, with the code i can generate automatically the class diagram? is possible know the bussines rules trought the code?

Comment: The docs cover it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Start Visual Studio Installer, click "Single Component", "Code Tools", and check "Class Designer".
2. Right-click the project to be viewed, select "View", "View Class Diagram" or right-click the project, select Add, New Item, and create a new class diagram.
3. Finally, drag the project into the class diagram to generate the class diagram.

Comment: not in the community edition, I guess ?

Comment: @Christophe Hi, this method is tested in the VS 2022 community edition. Did you encounter any issues during use?